# how to add libraries in oracle form6i

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am very new to Oracle Forms.

In my project I have a pkg_voice.pll containing some functions and procedures. These are used in some triggers of another form.

When I opened my forms it displays an error: "pkg_voice. must be declared". I attached .pll library to that form.

Answer (score 2):

Did you removed the path when imported the library to the form? It seems that it cannot find that pll file at all or you are executing those procedures incorrectly (wrong parameters etc.)

Try to put pll file under same directory where your fmb is. Then open Oracle Forms with shortcut of it where you have defined "Start in" to same directory where your files are.

Answer (score 0):

Does your library `pkg_voice.pll` actually *contain* any procedure, function or package also called `pkg_voice`?

Remember, you don't actually refer to the PLL file name in your PL/SQL, but to the procedures, functions or packages defined inside the PLL.